# Is that possible if my reputation drops to zero (0)?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Just curious enough, so is that possible if my reputation drops to zero?

...

Why?

Comment: *"is that possible if my reputation drops to zero?"* What are you referring to with 'that'? And reputation can't drop below 1 as far as I know. In the right sidebar on the [privileges page](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) you can see what amount of reputation you need to access certain functionality of the site.

Comment: @gertvdijk : Because that I want know why reputation can/t drop to 0.

Comment: [Why does reputation have a lower bound of 1?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2621/195914), [Negative rep a real possibility?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165702/195914), [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/195914)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The minimum bound is 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2621/195914)(Thanks for the link gertvdijk). You are a beautiful and unique snowflake, and will melt under the withering heat of criticism if you had a negative score. Stackexchange as such does not have 0 or negative user reputation.

However, to achieve something close to a negative score (a -1) from any positive score, you'd need a string of bad questions or answers. This will result in either a manual suspension by a mod, or a question or answer ban through cold unfeeling machine. This of course, probably will be more annoying than a negative score, and probably means the same thing... other than having a reputation of 1 rather than over - 9000